# Is there any way to get all system available fonts for mac os and windows in .Net MAUI?

Tags: .net, maui

I have a scenario where i need to get the list of system available fonts which i will apply in a drop down picker and the user selected font family will be applied while drawing text on a skbitmap.

I want a list of font family strings to show in a drop down picker in .Net MAUI.

Comment: You can get the fonts from the Microsoft and apple system fonts doc. Here is the [Windows 10 font list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/fonts/windows_10_font_list) and [apple mac System Fonts list](https://developer.apple.com/fonts/system-fonts/).